# Select random 50% of sample, but only 1 person per couple

Tags: random, filter, spss

Essentially, I'm trying to do stratified random sampling. I want to run an analysis on data with heterosexual couples. I need to select a random 50% of women and a random 50% of men they are not married to. I know how to filter out a random percentage of the total sample, but not how to ensure that only one person per household is selected.

My data look like this:

`couple person gender Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4    Q5`

`1        1       0   3.5  4.2  2.3  3.3  4.3`

`1        2       1   3.2  2.5  2.1  3.7  5.6`

`2        1       1   3.7  2.6  3.3  4.2  5.1`

`2        2       0   3.0  3.5  2.1  3.6  5.4`

It's in long format, so each row represents a person and there are two people per couple.

EDITED for more details

`hhid` = couple
`hhidpn` = person
`ragender` = gender in which 1 = male, 2 = female
`SPAQ1-8` = items 1-8 of a self-perceptions of aging scale

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKQ7k.png
```

Comment: 1. Select a couple. 2. Select one member of the couple and reject the other.  You might need to think about how to handle same-sex marriages.

Comment: Thank you @rossum! There aren't any same-sex couples in this dataset. I'm afraid I'm not sure how to select one member of the couple and reject the other. Would you mind explaining further?

Comment: Pick a random number in, say, [0..99] If the number is odd then pick gender 1; if the number is even pick gender 0.  You may need to do a little adjusting if you want the two genders exactly equal.  You could alternate which gender you pick for example.

Comment: @rossum: If your comments are actually answers to the question, you should post them as such.  In general, you should avoid answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to randomly divide the couples in two equal groups, and then select the women in one group and the men in the other group.

First I'll reconstruct your example data to demonstrate on:

```
data list list/couple person gender (3f1) Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4    Q5 (5f2.1).
begin data
1  1  0   3.5  4.2  2.3  3.3  4.3
1  2  1   3.2  2.5  2.1  3.7  5.6
2  1  1   3.7  2.6  3.3  4.2  5.1
2  2  0   3.0  3.5  2.1  3.6  5.4
3  1  0   3.5  4.2  2.3  3.3  4.3
3  2  1   3.2  2.5  2.1  3.7  5.6
4  1  1   3.7  2.6  3.3  4.2  5.1
4  2  0   3.0  3.5  2.1  3.6  5.4
end data.
```

Now we have a dataset, we can do the sampling as you need:

*EDITED for a shorter process - using a version of @rossum's suggestion:*

```
* first we give each couple a random number, and then use it to sort the couples randomly.
sort cases by couple.
compute randorder=uniform(100).
if couple=lag(couple) randorder=lag(randorder).
sort cases by randorder.

* now we create a running index for the couples, and use it to select males 
or females according to odd or even index.
compute coupleNum=1.
if $casenum>1 coupleNum=lag(coupleNum)+(couple<>lag(couple)).
compute selected=(mod(coupleNum, 2)=gender).
exe.
```

Now you created your selection variable, you can use it with `filter` or with `select` to continue to the analysis.

EDIT:
The above code works for gender having values 0,1. The edit to the OP shows the values for gender are actually 1,2. So the final computation of `selected` should be done this way instead of as above:

```
compute selected=(mod(coupleNum, 2)+1=gender).
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I ran this code and the selected variable gives me a random 25% of all cases without any of them sharing a household. It looks like all my selected=1 cases are males. Do you know how I could add a random 50% of females who do not share a household with the selected males?

Comment: does the code work on the example for you? (it does for me...). If it works on the example but not on the original dataset, we have to try to understand what the difference is and create a better fitting example (and correct the code accordingly)

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for helping me. I am really grateful for your generosity. The example code did work for me, so I'm not sure what the difference is with my original data. I added a screenshot of my data in an edit to the original post in case you can see something I can't.

Comment: OK I think the values of gender are the problem - 0,1 in the example, 1,2 in the real data. please see my edit to take care of that.